# XSLT compare element value from different nodes - performance problem

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there a better way than two "for-loops" to assemble the node elements for the following XML data set / XML structure?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <nodeA>
        <nodeAa>
            <Row>
                <ID>100001</ID>
                <NAME>ABC</NAME>
                <EDV_NUMBER>900001</EDV_NUMBER>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <ID>100002</ID>
                <NAME>DEF</NAME>
                <EDV_NUMBER>900002</EDV_NUMBER>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <ID>700003</ID>
                <NAME>XYZ</NAME>
                <EDV_NUMBER>900002</EDV_NUMBER>
            </Row>
        </nodeAa>
    </nodeA>
    <nodeB>
        <nodeBa>
            <Row>
                <EDV_NUMBER>900001</EDV_NUMBER>
                <TYP>002</TYP>
            <Row>
                <EDV_NUMBER>900002</EDV_NUMBER>
                <TYP>002</TYP>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <EDV_NUMBER>900002</EDV_NUMBER>
                <TYP>009</TYP>
            </Row>
        </nodeBa>
    </nodeB>
</root>
```

The output file should contain all elements of node "//nodeBa/Row/*" including the elements (ID & NAME) of node "//nodeAa/Row/", where element "EDV_NUMBER"are the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CSV>
    <Row>
        <EDV_NUMBER>900001</EDV_NUMBER>
        <TYP>002</TYP>
        <ID>100001</ID>
        <NAME>ABC</NAME>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EDV_NUMBER>900002</EDV_NUMBER>
        <TYP>002</TYP>
        <ID>100002</ID>
        <NAME>DEF</NAME>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EDV_NUMBER>900002</EDV_NUMBER>
        <TYP>009</TYP>
        <ID>700003</ID>
        <NAME>XYZ</NAME>
    </Row>
</CSV>
```

The output can be generated with following code, but doesn't work well for big datasets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>  
     <xsl:template match="/">
     <CSV>
          <xsl:for-each select="/root/nodeB/nodeBa/Row">

               <xsl:variable name="FIBU" select="./EDV_NUMBER/text()"/>
               <xsl:variable name="TYP" select="./TYP/text()"/>     

               <Row select="{position()}">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="./*"/>

                    <xsl:for-each select="/root/nodeA/nodeAa/Row">
                    <xsl:variable name="counter" select="position()"/>  
                         <xsl:choose>
                              <xsl:when test="/root/nodeA/nodeAa/Row[$counter]/EDV_NUMMER/text()=$FIBU and $TYP='002' and /root/nodeA/nodeAa/Row[$counter]/TYP/text() &lt; '700000'">
                                   <xsl:copy-of select="./ID"/>
                                   <xsl:copy-of select="./NAME"/>
                              </xsl:when>
                              <xsl:when test="/root/nodeA/nodeAa/Row[$counter]/EDV_NUMMER/text()=$FIBU and $TYP='009' and /root/nodeA/nodeAa/Row[$counter]/TYP/text() &gt;= '700000'">
                                   <xsl:copy-of select="./ID"/>
                                   <xsl:copy-of select="./NAME"/>
                              </xsl:when>
                              <xsl:otherwise/>
                         </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:for-each>
               </Row>
          </xsl:for-each>
     </CSV>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to declare a key `<xsl:key name="nodea-ref" match="nodeA/nodeAa/Row" use="EDV_NUMMER"/>` and then use `<xsl:copy-of select="key('nodea-ref', EDV_NUMMER)/(ID, NAME)"/>` inside of the outer for-each.

Answer (score 2):

try replacing the inner loop with something like this:
It'll select all nodes in /root/nodeA with the same EDV_NUMBER than the current element of the outer loop

```
<xsl:when test="/root/nodeA/nodeAa/Row[EDV_NUMBER=$FIBU]">
<!-- ... -->
</xsl:when>
```